# Get specific column with NHibernate Query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have an application using NHibernate and C# language. I have an model with some relations and I want to create a query to get only one value. I've tried something like this:

```
public long GetIdCompany(long number)
{
    return session.QueryOver<Report>()
                  .Where(x => x.Number == number)
                  .Select(x => x.Equipament.Company.Id)
                  .Take(1);
}
```

but I didn't work. I just want to take the `IdCompany` in the the model `Report.Equipament.Company.Id`. It could be in queryover, linq, hql, etc...

Comment: As a side, you could probably shorten this to `.Where(x => x.Number == number).Single().[Id prop]`

Comment: what is not working ? can you show us an error message ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use `JoinAlias`, so your request will looks like

```
    public long GetIdCompany(long number)
    {
        Equipament equipamentAlias = null;
        return session.QueryOver<Report>()
                      .Where(x => x.Number == number)
                      .JoinAlias(x => x.Equipament, () => equipamentAlias)
                      .Select(x => equipamentAlias.Company.Id)
                      .SingleOrDefault<long>();
    }
```

Here is [excellent introduction to QueryOver](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

**HQL**

```
return session.CreateQuery(
        "select e.Company.id from Report r " +
        "    inner join r.Equipament e " +
        "where r.Number = :number")
    .SetInt64("number", number)
    .UniqueResult<long>();
```

**LINQ**

```
return session.Query<Report>()
    .Where(x => x.Number == number)
    .Select(x => x.Equipament.Company.Id)
    .Single();
```

**QueryOver**

See GSerjo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11695844/119230).

Comment: @GSerjo Thanks. Pointed to your answer.

Comment: Thank you Miroslav, I liked your awser but I would like to use QueryOVer.